# When to and not to use the particle の to link to nouns?

Tags: particles, nouns

I know that the particle の can be used for linking several nouns together or to indicate possession. However I have seen several cases where the の is droped. Like for example 未来日記. My question is when to and not to use the particle no?

Comment: 未来日記 is obviously different from 未来の日記 (diaries that will have been come into use in future), isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, if its unambiguous it can be dropped. This rule applies to most particles. You hear native speakers do it all the time.

やまださん(が)くるの？

Is Yamada coming?

I can't think of too many instances where の is dropped off the top of my head but I its pretty common.